# Adding Editable pdfcell in ItextSharp Header

Tags: itext

I need to add an Editable pdfcell on the Header or the First content in every new page. I have a Editanle pdfcell on the First page as the first item , then I have a table table that sometimes move in to multiple pages whenever the new page starts , i want to add that text box with the content again. Please hel me as I can add only the text as of now and not the text box.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a [`PdfPageEvent`](http://api.itextpdf.com/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPageEventHelper.html) that adds your text field to each page.

You can probably reuse the exact same `PdfFormField` object, so long as they're all in the same spot on the page.

Keep in mind that pdf fields with the same full name have the same value... This sounds like what you want, but maybe not.